# Proximal Mapping for maximum of linear and quadratic function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I was wondering if there is an efficient way of calculating the proximal mapping of the following function $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $b_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$ :
$$
f(y) = \max \{ \frac{1}{2} \| y \|^2 + b_1^T y + c_1, b_2^T y + c_2 \},
$$
i.e.
$$\arg \underset{y \in \mathbb{R}^3} \min \, f(y) + \frac{1}{2 \sigma} \| y - y^0 \|^2.$$

Right now I'm considering to use subgradient descent, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient variant.

Comment: "Right now I'm considering to use subgradient descent" Do you mean using subgradient descent to compute this proximal mapping?  If you're going to evaluate this prox operator numerically, I'm sure there are better methods than the subgradient method (which is quite slow).

Comment: Yes, I'm planning on solving that proximal mapping using subgradient descent. I would be glad to hear about better methods to solve that problem. Since $f$ is non-differentiable, Newton's method does not seem to be applicable directly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone can find an analytical formula for this prox operator, but if we're going to evaluate it numerically then one option is to reformulate our optimization problem as
\begin{align}
\operatorname{minimize}_{y,t} & \quad t + \frac{1}{2 \sigma} \|y - y^0 \|^2 \\
\text{subject to} & \quad t \geq b_2^T y + c_2 \\
& \quad t \geq \frac12 \|y \|^2 + b_1^T y + c_1.
\end{align}
This problem can then be solved using interior point methods.  (For example we could solve this using CVX in Matlab.)

This trick of introducing $t$ is used a lot in convex optimization.